# Which one is correct: "1yr" or "1yr." or "1 yr"?

Tags: grammatical-number, abbreviations, spacing

I need to put one of the above on one of my app's buttons.

Bonus question - does the same rule hold in plural? That is if I write "1 yr.", do I write "15 yrs." as well?

Comment: Is your button really so small you can't afford the two extra characters of the full word?

Comment: @Ed - good point. it's a mobile app, so the space is extremely precious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As reported by the *Oxford Living Dictionaries* (and similarly by the copy of the *New Oxford American English* that was installed on my Mac Mini) [*yr.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/yr.) is an English abbreviation, but it could be both the abbreviation of *year* or *years*, while [*yrs.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/yrs.) is the abbreviation for *years* or *yours*. In this case, you could use *1 yr.*, *2 yr.* and the abbreviation would always be correct.

As reported from the *Oxford Dictionary of English*, it's the same in British English, except the abbreviation is written without a period at the end (e.g. *yr* instead of *yr.*).

As the other answers says, there should be a space between the number and *yr.*/*yrs.*.

Comment: Note: In British English there is no full stop: "1 yr" not "1 yr.".

Comment: @Charles, Seriously? [Citation](http://xkcd.com/285) needed.

Comment: @Pacerier: For a quick introduction to British English abbreviations, see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/punctuation-in-abbreviations

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the rules for spacing or not spacing between values and units is that there should always be a spacing between the value and the unit ("1 %" is incorrect, since percent is not a unit, but a fraction). Hence, "1yr" is incorrect, since "year" is a unit.

I'd write "1 yr", "15 yrs" if I really needed the space. In all other cases I'd prefer "1 year", "15 years", since "yr" doesn't look that good in text, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on context.

In geology `yr` is the recognised symbol for years, when talking about absolute age.

Although there has been some controversy recently. See this New Scientist article: http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20423-push-to-define-year-sparks-time-war.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there's no correct one, but `1 yr.` (or `2 yrs.`) come closest, based on convention.

Comment: I'll go with "1 yr", without a dot (as it is a recognised symbol, at least in geology :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem I run into with "1 yr" is in wrapping text, the "1" and "yr" can end up on separate lines.
It also looks odd in context. "the 1 yr return was 5%".   Vs "the 1yr return was 5%".

Plus spell-check goes after "yr" as an error. I don't want to add "yr" as a word in my dictionary.

So I go against convention and vote for "1yr". No space.