# Should "days" be abbreviated when in the context of other abbreviated words?

Tags: abbreviations

When writing "1 week 3 days," if week is abbreviated to wk., should days also be abbreviated? If so, what should it be abbreviated to?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with 10 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abbreviation for day is "d".

> 2wk 3d

This abbreviation is rarely used, however is considered acceptable in certain contexts, one being when used in conjunction with other time abbreviations.

Comment: If using American English, shouldn't the abbreviations both have periods?

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed I usually see time abbreviations written without the period, however, [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24150/184021) may answer your question. It seems like there is a difference between the American and British Oxford Dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is yes, that for consistency, you should abbreviate both. However, it might make more sense to write is as "10 days", depending on the context.

Comment: I think the total number of days is ten.

Comment: @PephenKinD oops, I was looking at the answer from Tot Zam